# trying to connect to my server but ISP blocks port forwarding

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I used to have a small server in my home, which is always connected to the internet
I would store my stuff there and be able to get them from anywhere in the world
but I had a little problem, that's my ISP (the one my server connected to) blocks port forwarding, So I had to use a remote administration tool (LEGAL) installed on that server with a ddns name to be able to control it, I would enable port forwarding on my pc so that the RAT would connect back to me (here my pc is the server and my server is the client "reverse tcp connection”).

Things were smooth until I travelled to UAE , the problem now is that my ISP in UAE also blocks port forwarding , so I have port forwarding blocked from both sides, and I'm no longer able to access my server back home , 
I tried to contact my ISP provider but they said I have to convert to an expensive business plan to be able to enable port forwarding.
I also tried to use ngrok but the It gives random port for tcp tunnelling and my client only uses port 443 
However it does let you specify the source port when you use http tunnelling (can I tunnel tcp through http without having access to the client?) 
I tried using PPTP VPN but my ISP is blocking it too. 
So to sum things up, I have two machines, the client and the server, the client has a RAT installed on it that connects to the server through a specific ddns and port (443) "example.ddns:443" using a reverse tcp connection. 
Now the server can no longer be accessed by the client because port forwarding is blocked. 
I have access to the ddns so I can change the IP my client will connect to anytime but I can't change the port or the protocol used (tcp) 
How can I tunnel the connection between me and my client?

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: Have you tried an OpenVPN vpn?

Comment: sadly OpenVPN is also closed .
is there any type of encrypted tunneling that support port forwarding ?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, but now Im using Ngrok, https://ngrok.com its simple, its free for what you want to do. You can create a free personal account. It allows you to forward your home's server contents to their subdomain, or on a comercial account into your own website domain or subdomain. So far I had no luck unblocking ISP to do reverse SSH. Good Luck

UPDATE... Oh, sorry I missed that you already used NGROK, but I solved it by using a Windows PC standalone server to retransmit my data from ngrok (if you dont turn off that PC it does not change the ramdom number) to any other site using IIs 6 with custom config ports for CORS headers so I did solve my problem. You could probably do the same.

Comment: The question says that the OP tried ngrok.  I can’t tell from your post whether you actually had the same problem, or just a “similar” one, and whether you actually solved it.  If you had the same problem as the OP, *and you solved it with ngrok,* then explain how you did it in detail (bearing in mind that they tried it and failed). … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.